# Uninitialized variable that has been initialized

Tags: java

Would anyone know why I am getting the error `Variable 'tree' might not have been initialized`

my method

```
public static TreeNode randomBST(TreeNode[] nodeArr) {
        TreeNode root = nodeArr[0];
        TreeNode tree;
        for (int i = 1; i < nodeArr.length; i++) {
            tree = buildBST(root, nodeArr[i]);
        }
        return tree;
    }
```

my buildBST method returns a TreeNode object.

I can fix this error by by assigning `tree = null`. How come I have to do this but if I were to initialize an `int` I dont have to? Is it because `int` is able to allocate a known amount of memory, where as the `tree` object is unknown amount of memory allocated?

Comment: Please show an example where it would work with `tree` being an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee to the compiler that the loop is ever entered. Thus the variable may not be initialized.